# Migrating git-based site workflow to new server

Tags: migration, git, website

I have a production site that uses a hub/master git setup like this: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Looking to migrate to a new server/host and I'm wondering how I migrate the git setup so as to maintain the development history.

Thanks.

Comment: all git repositories are more or less freestanding, which means that you can do `git clone` and all history will be included (as long as they are in branches or tags)